# My json object outputs only one object but there is more in my xml file

Tags: php, json, xml

This is my JSON Output and i will like it more objects

```
[
    {
        "EcommerceProductGuid": "1282174A-F6A9-4049-8C03-EFDBF065A22F",
        "ProductNumber": "-004394",
        "Description": "Sparta Ion DLI D50",
        "Type": "Ion DLI M-Gear",
        "Kind": "Elektrische fiets",
        "Brand": "Sparta",
    }
]
```

and this is my PHP

```
function XMLtoJSON($xml) {
    $xml = file_get_contents($xml);    // gets XML content from file
    $xml = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $xml);    // removes newlines, returns and tabs

    // replace double quotes with single quotes, to ensure the simple XML function can parse the XML
    $xml = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $xml));
    $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);


    // loop over Products -> Product item in the xml file
    $devices = array();
    foreach($simpleXml->Products->Product as $product)
    {

        $device = array();
        foreach($product as $key => $value)
        {
            //$device[(string)$rewriteKeys[$key]] = (string)$value;
            $device[(string)$key] = (string)$value;

            // unset empty and extra keys
            unset($device['epg']);
            unset($device[null]);
        }


    $devices[] = $product;

    return stripslashes(json_encode($devices, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));    // returns a string with JSON object
}
```

The Problem is that he only output one Product object but my XML file contains 4 of them.

Comment: return your json data outside for loop and than see the result

Comment: Do you mean outside the function? but i think he's already outside the loop right?

Comment: not outside the function  where is your loop end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems towards the end of the script, you need to add the devices into the array inside the main loop, but output the JSON after the end of all loops (you where returning the data at the end of the first loop).

```
// loop over Products -> Product item in the xml file
$devices = array();
foreach($simpleXml->Products->Product as $product)
{

    $device = array();
    foreach($product as $key => $value)
    {
        //$device[(string)$rewriteKeys[$key]] = (string)$value;
        $device[(string)$key] = (string)$value;
    }
    // unset empty and extra keys after transferring all values
    unset($device['epg']);
    unset($device[null]);

    // Add device into array inside loop
    $devices[] = $product;
}

// Return data after processing all product in loop
return stripslashes(json_encode($devices, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));    // returns a string with JSON object
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing `}` for the first `foreach`. Thus the `return` is always executed within the first loop of the first `foreach`:

```
function XMLtoJSON($xml) {
    $xml = file_get_contents($xml);    // gets XML content from file
    $xml = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $xml);    // removes newlines, returns and tabs

    // replace double quotes with single quotes, to ensure the simple XML function can parse the XML
    $xml = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $xml));
    $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);


    // loop over Products -> Product item in the xml file
    $devices = array();
    foreach($simpleXml->Products->Product as $product)
    {

        $device = array();
        foreach($product as $key => $value)
        {
            //$device[(string)$rewriteKeys[$key]] = (string)$value;
            $device[(string)$key] = (string)$value;

            // unset empty and extra keys
            unset($device['epg']);
            unset($device[null]);
        }
    $devices[] = $product;
    } // THIS WAS MISSING

    return stripslashes(json_encode($devices, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));    // returns a string with JSON object
}
```